# Concatenating mp4 files on run time using red5.io

Tags: java, red5

I was recently working on an old project where we concatenates multiple flv files. The approach was:

1. Read the file through FLVReader(Red5.io).
2. Append the file tags using FLVWriter(Red5.io) by implementing ITagWriter interface.
3. Adding the meta data for the new file.

Now, what we want to use this same approach to concatenates the mp4 file using the red5.io library. The problem is: We have MP4Reader available at Red5 but not the MP4Writer.

And I am very confuse to implement this interface. Is there anyone who have already wrote this down? Or help me with some approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no MP4Writer at this time 9/2019; to implement one, the same pattern as the FLVWriter may be followed, but you'd have to use an MP4 writing library to do the actual file I/O passing NALU or whatever the library is configured for.